# ValueError : I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python, csv, file-io, io

```
import csv    

with open('v.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    cwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

for w, c in p.items():
    cwriter.writerow(w + c)
```

Here, `p` is a dictionary, `w` and `c` both are strings.

When I try to write to the file it reports the error:

```
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Answer (score 227, accepted):

Indent correctly; your `for` statement should be inside the [`with`](https://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) block:

```
import csv    

with open('v.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    cwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    for w, c in p.items():
        cwriter.writerow(w + c)
```

Outside the `with` block, the file is closed.

```
>>> with open('/tmp/1', 'w') as f:
...     print(f.closed)
... 
False
>>> print(f.closed)
True
```

Answer (score 11):

**Same error** can raise by **mixing**: tabs + spaces.

```
with open('/foo', 'w') as f:
 (spaces OR  tab) print f       <-- success
 (spaces AND tab) print f       <-- fail
```

Comment: True, but this is always the case in python when mixing them up right?

Answer (score 1):

**I also have the same problem.
Here is my previous code**

```
csvUsers = open('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Ada/Users.csv', 'a', newline='', encoding='utf8')
usersWriter = csv.writer(csvUsers)
for t in users:
    NodeWriter=.writerow(users)
csvUsers.close()
```

**Apparently, I shoud write the usersWriter instead of NodeWriter.**

```
NodeWriter=.writerow(users)
usersWriter=.writerow(users)
```

**Below is my current code and it is working**

```
csvUsers = open('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Ada/Users.csv', 'a', newline='', encoding='utf8')
usersWriter = csv.writer(csvUsers)
for t in users:
    usersWriter=.writerow(users)
csvUsers.close()
```

Comment: Isn't `NodeWriter=.writerow(users)` a syntax error? `=.` is not in any Python grammar, is it?

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open("filename.txt", newline='')
for row in self.data:
    print(row)
```

Save data to a variable(`file`), so you need a `with`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I was using an undefined variable inside the `with open(...) as f:`.
I removed (or I defined outside) the undefined variable and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause is the case when, after a round of copypasta, you end up reading two files and assign **the same name to the two file handles**, like the below. Note the nested `with open` statement.

```
with open(file1, "a+") as f:
    # something...
    with open(file2, "a+", f):
        # now file2's handle is called f!

    # attempting to write to file1
    f.write("blah") # error!!
```

The fix would then be to assign different variable names to the two file handles, e.g. `f1` and `f2` instead of both `f`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem after using auto-py-to-exe to compile my program.

I used `with open(link, "rb") as f:` but switching to `PdfReader` method fixed it.

Just wanted to share in case someone else faces this.

```
# it diesn't work --> ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
     for link in links:
                if os.path.isfile(link):
                    with open(link, "rb") as f:
                    pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(f)
            pdf_exporter.write("C:\\Temp\\test.pdf")
            os.startfile("C:\\Temp\\test.pdf")

# it does
     for link in links:
                if os.path.isfile(link):
                    # with open(link, "rb") as f:
                    # pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(f)
                    pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(link)
            pdf_exporter.write("C:\\Temp\\test.pdf")
            os.startfile("C:\\Temp\\test.pdf")
```