# How to upload an image file to MongoDB with Bottle framework and Mongoengine?

Tags: python, mongodb, bottle, mongoengine

I need to upload image file to MongoDB using mongoengine and Bottle framework.
There is my python code:

```
from bottle import Bottle, run, route, post, debug, request, template, response
from mongoengine import *


connect('imgtestdb')


app = Bottle()


class Image(Document):
    img_id = IntField()
    img_src = ImageField()


@app.route('/img/<image>')
def get_img(image):
    img = Image.objects(img_id=image)[0].img_src
    response.content_type = 'image/jpeg'

    return img


@app.route('/new')
def new_img_form():
    return template('new.tpl')


@app.post('/new')
def new_img():
    img_id = request.forms.get('id')
    img_src = request.files.get('upload')

    img = Image()
    img.img_id = img_id
    img.img_src.put(img_src, content_type = 'image/jpeg')
    img.save()



app.run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True, reloader=True)
```

And template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/new" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Image ID: <input type="text" name="id" />
  Select a file: <input type="file" name="upload" />
  <input type="submit" value="Start upload" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I try upload a image, it gives an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/mongoengine/fields.py", line 1311, in put
    img = Image.open(file_obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2000, in open
    prefix = fp.read(16)
AttributeError: 'FileUpload' object has no attribute 'read'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 862, in _handle
    return route.call(**args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 1728, in wrapper
    rv = callback(*a, **ka)
  File "./imgtest.py", line 38, in new_img
    img.img_src.put(img_src, content_type = 'image/jpeg')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/mongoengine/fields.py", line 1314, in put
    raise ValidationError('Invalid image: %s' % e)
mongoengine.errors.ValidationError: Invalid image: 'FileUpload' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Is it possible to upload an image file from Bottle request to MongoDB?

I just tried to save the file:

```
@app.route('/upload', method='POST')
def do_upload():
    img_id = request.forms.get('imgid')
    upload = request.files.get('upload')

    upload.save('tmp/{0}'.format(img_id))
```

It returns error:

```
ValueError('I/O operation on closed file',)
```

Then I tried open file before save upload:

```
@app.route('/upload', method='POST')
def do_upload():
    upload = request.files.get('upload')

    with open('tmp/1.jpg', 'w') as open_file:
        open_file.write(upload.file.read())
```

Error:

```
ValueError('read of closed file',)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First all img_src is instance of class bottle.FileUpload. It not have read(). Basically save the file and open again. Make test below. Good luck!

```
import os

from bottle import route, run, template, request
from mongoengine import Document, IntField, ImageField, connect

connect('bottle')

class Image(Document):
    img_id = IntField()
    img_src = ImageField()

@route('/home')
def home():
    return template('upload')

@route('/upload', method='POST')
def do_upload():
    img_id = request.forms.get('id')
    img_src = request.files.get('upload')
    name = img_src.filename

    # your class ...
    img = Image()
    img.img_id = img_id
    # img_src is class bottle.FileUpload it not have read()
    # you need save the file
    img_src.save('.') # http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/_modules/bottle.html#FileUpload

    # mongoengine uses PIL to open and read the file
    # https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow/blob/master/PIL/Image.py#L2103
    # open temp file
    f = open(img_src.filename, 'r')

    # saving in GridFS...
    img.img_src.put(f)
    img.save()

    return 'OK'

run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Comment: Return `ValueError('I/O operation on closed file',)`

Comment: Ok! It's fine! :) Now, the problem is handling file. Try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18952716/valueerror-i-o-operation-on-closed-file

Answer (score 0):

true that if img_src is a bottle.FileUpload instance it has no .read() method

but then img_src.file is a _io.BufferedRandom so it has .read() method.

so you can do directly :

```
file_h = img_src.file
img = Image.open(file_h)
```

still, trying to open it with Pillow 2.5 Image.open() gave me a "ValueError: read of closed file" (exception came from Image.open() and fp.read(16) call in it)

upgrading Bottle from 0.12 to 0.12.7 did the trick and this exception vanished.
hope it helps.