# Finding the number of values greater than a particular value (using a csv file)

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, if-statement

I have a csv file named 'datavalues.csv'. It has about 20,000 values and I am curious as to how many of those values are over 10,000.

I have the below code, but I keep getting the following error `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import csv

with open('datavalues.csv', 'rb') as datavalues:
  datavaluesreader = csv.reader(datavalues, delimiter=',')

print(sum(x >= 10000 for x in datavaluesreader))
```

Comment: Try moving the `print` inside the `with`. Still, the data may be strings, so you have to convert them to integers.

Comment: `x` is the row. You have to select a cell and convert to integer. e.g `sum(int(x[0]) >= 10000 for x in datavaluesreader)`

Answer (score 1):

Look this [ValueError : I/O operation on closed file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18952716/valueerror-i-o-operation-on-closed-file). I think that is your problem. The usage of `datavaluesreader` is not inside the scope of the `with` statement, and so by the time it is executed the underlying file has been closed.