# How to create a program that writes a print("hello world"), in the main file where the original program was written?

Tags: python

If I want to run a program that writes a print("hello world") in the code of my main file, where I wrote the original program, how would I do that in Python?

I thought something like:

```
 import main


 with open("main.py " , "a+") as file_object:
    
      file_object.seek(0)

      data = file_object.read(100)

      if len(data)>0:

            file_object.write("\n")

      file_object.write('print("hello world)')
```

but the console shows this:

> ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Comment: You are trying to do an operation on a closed file. Also the indentation of the code is wrong. Try changing the indentation of the code. Without so many line breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `__file__` which gives you the path of your file and then append your text to it.

```
path = __file__

f = open(path, "a")
f.write('\nprint("hello world")')
f.close()
```

Answer (score 4):

From my understanding, you are trying to determine if a file has content and if it does include a new line, and then append the print statement.

You do not need to use seek you can just check the size of the file:

```
import os

if os.path.getsize(filename):
    # file isn't empty
else:
    # file is empty
```

You should also close the quotation marks in your print statement

Comment: hii @djsokol , how are you?    my goal is not to know if there is something inside the file, but how to create a program that writes a print("hello world"), in the main file where the original program was written

Comment: would you know how i could do this?

Answer (score 0):

you wrong because Indent correctly, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18952716/valueerror-i-o-operation-on-closed-file). You can modify like:

```py
import main


with open("main.py" , "a+") as file_object:

    file_object.seek(0)
    data = file_object.read(100)
    if len(data)>0:
        file_object.write("\n")

    file_object.write('print("hello world")')
```

Comment: hii  @Viettel Solutions ,  how are you?, Sorry but I don't understand what you mean, can you explain better??