# Jupyter Notebook cell run doesn't finalize

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

When I run Python code in the jupyter notebook, I got the following error, and cell doesn't finalize.

However, if I run the same Python code in the command line, it finishes its run without any problem.

```
[IPKernelApp] ERROR | Exception in message handler:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/burcakotlu/developer/python/test_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 424, in dispatch_shell
    await result
  File "/Users/burcakotlu/developer/python/test_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 770, in execute_request
    sys.stderr.flush()
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
[IPKernelApp] ERROR | Error in message handler
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/burcakotlu/developer/python/test_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 529, in dispatch_queue
    await self.process_one()
  File "/Users/burcakotlu/developer/python/test_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 518, in process_one
    await dispatch(*args)
  File "/Users/burcakotlu/developer/python/test_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 437, in dispatch_shell
    sys.stderr.flush()
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

I haven't solved this issue for days. I would appreciate any help.

Env specific versions:

```
$ pip list | grep -E "(^jup|^ipy)"
ipykernel                  6.27.1
ipython                    8.18.1
jupyter_client             8.6.0
jupyter_core               5.5.0
```

Comment: It'll help if we see the relevant code. Unless it's *any* code.

Comment: Python code is calling other python packages.

Comment: "Python code is calling other python packages." is not code. Please be precise.

Comment: The traceback seems to be from the server / terminal. Is there any error message in the notebook itself?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18952716/valueerror-i-o-operation-on-closed-file may help but it is hard to diagnose without seeing the actual code that may be causing the error.

Comment: No, in the notebook there is no error message, only the cell is not finalizing with [*].

Comment: How did you start the jupyter-notebook-server? Did you redirect stderr? Because the error seems to indicate that the server cant flush stderr, which is very unusual

Comment: This problem seems to be in the error-handling of the server. That means the server encountered an error (which may or may not be related to OPs code) but then failed to handle the error due to something to do with the stderr. The latter part has nothing to do with OPs code. Please tell us about the server: how did you start it? What terminal/OS? A process should be able to flush stderr.

Comment: @julaine I'm starting Jupyter Notebook in my terminal after activating my virtual environment at MACOS Monterey version 12.6.

Comment: @burcak try different ways of starting it. without the venv for example, or with a different terminal emulator.

Comment: @julaine, what are the different terminal options other than the one that comes with MACOS by default?

Comment: @burcak I don't know mac very much. I just suspect this is to do with how you start this server. Include that in the question for others to see and maybe they will know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help. Comments from @julaine writing that **the server can't flush stderr, which is very unusual** wake me up.

I remembered that somewhere in my code I have done the following.

```
sys.stderr = open(error_file, 'w')
...
...
...
sys.stderr.close()
```

So I had redirected the sys.stderr to a file and then closed it.
Then I got the following error

```
sys.stderr.flush()
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Changing the code as follows solved the issue:

```
temp = sys.stderr 
sys.stderr = open(error_file, 'w')
...
...
...
sys.stderr.close()
sys.stderr = temp
```

Redirecting sys.stderr to what it was pointing before resolved the problem.

There is even a better solution without using a temporary variable.

```
sys.stderr = open(error_file, 'w')
...
...
...
sys.stderr.close()
sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__
```